# Efficiently compute two dissimilar numbers in arm neon

Tags: c++, arm, intrinsics, neon

I have an array of 16 integers and I'd like to find pair of ints from this array that have max dissimilarity between each other.
dissimilarity could be computed with this (pseudo) code:

```
int diss(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{   // it could do square for each byte of the number instead.
    return
    abs(((x >> 24) & 0xFF) - ((y >> 24) & 0xFF)) + 
    abs(((x >> 16) & 0xFF) - ((y >> 16) & 0xFF)) + 
    abs(((x >>  8) & 0xFF) - ((y >>  8) & 0xFF)) + 
    abs(((x >>  0) & 0xFF) - ((y >>  0) & 0xFF));
}

void findDissimilar(uint32_t buf[16], uint32_t& x, uint32_t& y)
{
    int maxDiss = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<16; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<16; ++j)
        {
            int d = diss(buf[i], bud[j]);
            if (d > maxDiss)
            {
                maxDiss = d;
                x = buf[i];
                y = buf[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On input `buf` is already in neon registers if that matters. On output I should get two ints (in neon reg perhaps it's better).
How can I do that efficiently in arm neon, what approaches should I try? Just to clarify, the point of the question is about optimizing `findDissimilar`.

Comment: So you're doing 4-byte SAD (sum of absolute differences), and looking for the pair that has the maximum SAD?

Comment: Yes, something like that. I think I've seen that somewhere in ffmpeg or x264, I'll try to grep to see if they have something similar.

Comment: Yes, x264 should have some 4x4 SAD motion search, including an exhaustive one.  But it will be looking at different colour planes separately, for blocks of 4x4 pixels.  So the motion-search will check every byte offset, not just in steps of 4 bytes.  But you might get an idea of some useful instructions for byte-wise SAD with NEON, if you can separate that out from shuffling / unaligned loads.

Comment: x264 has multiple search patterns to look for a good match quickly, not necessarily the minimum SAD: `dia` (diagonal), `hex` (hexagon), `umh` (uneven multi-hexagon), and `esa` (exhaustive, but not a brute-force check of every alignment).  `tesa` finds the minimum-cost DCT-transformed residual, instead of the minimum SAD.  Also note that x264 will have 8x8 and 16x16 SADs for motion-searching on larger blocks.

Comment: How are you using the result?  Do you want a SIMD vector of results for multiple 16-element buffers, or is this only ever used on one 16-byte vector at once?  (Not sure if that makes a difference, but it easily might.  And there might be a throughput vs. latency tradeoff.)  And just to confirm, you only want the numbers themselves, *not* the position?

Comment: I need just two `x` and `y` numbers in neon regs. For now I want to write `findDissimilar` for one block, on later stages I'll see if I can process multiple blocks for optimization purposes.

Comment: @PeterCordes I wanted to clarify in the question that I need only numbers, not positions because with positions it would be more complex. So, yes, only the numbers :)

Comment: You will have to permute the vectors to four bytes, then apply the `vabd` instruction.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE any more details? I'll give as answer my approach

Comment: `You will have to permute the vectors to four bytes` - what do you mean? `vabd` part is trivial, actual `findDissimilar` isn't that simple

Comment: Sorry, this problem contradicts with one of my current clients'. I'm obliged not to provide you any further details on this. (I've been warned)

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE You mean it it's technically similar and contradicts contractually or something like that?

Comment: Yes, I already wrote the function solving this problem some time ago, but I'm on contract. And they are mad at me.

Comment: Mad? If you did your job well, why would they be mad? The thing is that I don't see how permute to four bytes could possibly work here, or even if that part is relevant at all to the question. Imagine that diss returns `(x-y)*(x-y)` without touching individual bytes, then there is no permute involved. The rest of `findDissimilar` is something that's not trivial. I described possible solution bellow, I think it should work well here.

Answer (score 0):

`diss` is trivial to compute in neon, it could possibly implemented this way (untested code):

```
uint32x4_t diss_x4(uint32x4_t x4, uint32x4_t y4)
{
    uint8x16_t diff = vabdq_u8(vreinterpretq_u8_u32(x4), vreinterpretq_u8_u32(x4));
    uint16x8_t m0 = vmull_u8(vget_low_u8(diff), vget_low_u8(diff));
    uint16x8_t m1 = vmull_u8(vget_high_u8(diff), vget_high_u8(diff));
    uint16x4_t s0 = vpadd_u16(vget_low_u8(m0), vget_high_u8(m0));
    uint16x4_t s1 = vpadd_u16(vget_low_u8(m1), vget_high_u8(m1));
    uint16x4_t sx = vpadd_u16(s0, s1);
    return vmovl_u16(sx);
}
```

but not so trivial to `findDissimilar`. I think the best approach is to do the following:
 - load all 16 ints in 4 q-registers `{q0, q1, q2, q3}`.
 - first q0 reg contains `{ buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3] }`
 - then I can loop 15 times and extract from the 4 input q regs into a qext values such as vextq_u32(q0, q1, 1) for the first iteration and so on.
 - compute minimums between q0 and qext.

then the same process should be done for q1, q2, q3.

Perhaps if I deinterleave `{q0, q1, q2, q3}` by byte it could be optimized even better.

Comment: So NEON has a SAD instruction?  You should at least say what it is if you want to post this as an answer.  You can't just do byte-element subtraction and take the signed absolute value, because that only works for absolute unsigned differences of 128 and smaller.

Comment: @PeterCordes not sure exactly what you mean. The dissimilarity calculation is not relevant here (I updated with sample code), the `findDissimilarity` is complex to do in neon and I described possible solution. Didn't try to implement it though

Comment: You said it was trivial, so I assumed there must be some direct hardware support.  Anyway, yes `vabdq_u8` gives you absolute differences; that's what I was wondering about. The rest of the function (2 multiplies and 3 adds) doesn't look very cheap, and obviously it took you some work to come up with it, so I'd hardly call it trivial.

Comment: Would `vabal_u8` (absolute diff and accumulate) be useful?  It apparently accumulates horizontally into a `uint16x8_t` vector.

Comment: No, diss is very trivial, I wrote it right here in a couple of mins. `findDissimilar` is basically the point of the question, it's not trivial at all. Just think about it, how something like that could possibly be implemented in simd logically (regardless is that's neon or sse/avx). Depending on impl of `diss` vadal might be useful (if diss computes sum of differences. .. Oh, I just realized that in my neon provided code I actually do sum of squares: I think this version of `diss` should produce better results for my algorithm.

Comment: I wouldn't use NEON in the first place on ARMv7, or even on ARMv6. `usad8` is the one powerful instruction that isn't available on ARMv8.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE True, this one extremely useful if `diss` is just a sum of differences as I originally wrote in question. If differences are squared (I'll use squares most likely), then it's it won't work. But in any case, point of the question about possible approaches that could be used for optimizing `findDissimilar` and this one without neon would be slower IMO.